# Including script in react app decreases lighthouse performance score a lot

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, smartsupp

I have been testing out what is causing my low lighthouse score and it seems when I remove the following script, it goes up by 30%! And I am not sure why.

Here is the script (smartupp - a web chat help app)

```
<script
                    defer
                    type="text/javascript"
                    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: `
                        var _smartsupp = _smartsupp || {};
_smartsupp.key = 'key';
window.smartsupp||(function(d) {
  var s,c,o=smartsupp=function(){ o._.push(arguments)};o._=[];
  s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];c=d.createElement('script');
  c.type='text/javascript';c.charset='utf-8';c.async=true;
  c.src='https://www.smartsuppchat.com/loader.js?';s.parentNode.insertBefore(c,s);
})(document);
                    ` }}
                />
```

I include that near the end of my pages.
When I include that, in lighthouse score it says "Reduce unused JavaScript" and I think because smartupp includes the following:
[image]

Does anyone have any ideas why this script slows my performance so much? And what I can do to improve it.

I am using NextJs (React).

Answer (score 1):

You load the whole chat app at page load. But you would only probably use it when user clicks on some button.
My suggestion would be to add a button with same design and load this smartsuppchat script only after user clicks on it.
There would be some additional logic needed to open the chat after loading but you would need to consult smartsuppchat documentation for that.

Comment: I have "defer" on the script and thought that would help so it doesnt count towards the lighthouse performance score. How come though?
Yeah maybe i need an intermediate button, but feels wrongs. Surely smartsupp should be smart enough.

Comment: those 3rd party tools rarely smart enough, defer would parse script after page parsed but still before user clicks buton (before TTI so lighthouse counts it against you)